# Retrieving Achievements and leaderboard data from third party android games

Tags: android, google-plus

How to retrieve achievements and leaderboard data of third party android games  installed in our users android device from our own android application?

If we create a android game , we are able to retrieve the players in our Google plus circle and their achievements data inside our game  by integrating with Google play game services.

But our current requirement is retrieving other game achievements data from our application.

Any ideas?